# Is every diagonal matrix the product of 3 matrices, $P^{-1}AP$, and why?

Tags: linear-algebra

In trying to figure out which matrices are diagonalizable, why does my textbook pursue the topic of similar matrices?

It says that "an $n \times n$ matrix A is diagonalizable when $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix. That is, $A$ is diagonalizable when there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix." I do not understand why it would begin with considering similar matrices. I mean, what is the motivation?

Comment: Didn't your instructor or your textbook give some motivation at all for doing this? :-|

Comment: A $3\times 3$ matrix gives a function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$.  Similar matrices give the same function under different coordinate systems.  So the concept is pretty basic and fundamental.

Comment: They are doing it to annoy you.

Comment: The textbook frames it as such, but it seems to be such a leap in logic to say that a matrix is diagonalizable when it is similar to a diagonal matrix. In fact, it is quite a different thing to say that matrix A is diagonalizable if and only if it is similar to a diagonal matrix, which the textbook does not state but very clearly implies.

Comment: Why is it a leap of logic?! Being diagonalizable means **exactly** being similar to diagonal matrix...

Comment: How can one reach a diagonal matrix besides, first, multiplying a qualifying matrix by a matrix of the same dimension and, second, premultiplying that product by the matrix of the same dimension's inverse? To say that one will endeavor to find such square matrices such that the similarity relation is satisfied between it and its "diagonal" equivalent is one thing. To question the veracity of the similarity relation is quite entirely something else. What is posited is "when" and not "if and only if". When you say "**means**", that presupposes that this is a definition. It should be a theorem.

Comment: No, there is no reason why it should be a theorem. And, in fact, it isn't. It is the definition of diagonalizability. Calling it a «leap of reason» will not help you understand linear algebra...

Comment: Why is it not a theorem to posit that for every diagonal matrix, there exist two matrices, A and B, such that the diagonal matrix is equal to the product of $A \times B \times A^{-1}$?

Comment: Because for $D$ a diagonal matrix, $D = IDI^{-1}$ always works, and it's a very boring theorem. Per "if and only if" not being part of the *definition*, it's quite customary to say things like "Such an object is called XYZ, when it satisfies ABC condition(s)". This is just something you'll have to get used to, or be annoyed about forever. It's just rare to see "if and only if" in definitions; it's usually reserved for theorems.

Answer (score 2):

We say that two square matrices $A,B$ are similar if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1} BP$.

More to the point, however, two matrices are similar if they represent the **same linear transformation** viewed in **different coordinate systems**.

Let us write the above equation as

$$ PA = BP $$

Therefore $PAx = BPx$. If $P$ is my **change of coordinates** matrix, then this equation says that the following two procedures give the same result:

1. Multiply $x$ by $A$, then change coordinates using $P$.
2. Change the coordinates of $x$ using $P$, then multiply the result by $B$.

So diagonalizability is a statement about what a matrix $A$ "looks like" in a certain coordinate system. When you multiply a vector $x$ by a diagonal matrix $D$, it just multiplies the components of $x$ by the corresponding diagonal entries. So if $D = P^{-1}AP$, then this says that in the coordinates given by the matrix $P$, multiplication by $A$ just scales each component of a vector (written in the $P$-basis) by some fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Matrices are connected to linear maps of vector spaces, and theres a concept of a basis for vector spaces. (A basis is something so that every element is a can be written uniquely as a sum of the elements in the basis.)

Now, bases aren't unique, so if you want to see what your matrix looks like under  a different basis, this is equivalent to conjugating by the change of basis matrix as you've written above.

Now a matrix is said to be diagonalisable if there is *some* basis under which the matrix becomes diagonal.

If you read further on in your textbook, it should tell you all this.

Comment: The textbook does not shed light in this vein. In fact, if it shed any light in this vein, instead of saying "A is diagonalizable when there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix", it would have said "A is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix."